# How do I get the index of a Widget in onPreviewDrop() in a VerticalPanel?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, drag-and-drop

I use the example here: https://gwt-dnd.appspot.com/#InsertPanelExample with only one column.

The column is a VerticalPanel which contains many Widgets.

Using the VerticalPanelDropController I can register:

```
  @Override
  public void onDrop(DragContext context) {
    super.onDrop(context);
    final Widget widget = context.draggable;
    final int newIndex = columnPanel.getWidgetIndex(widget);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPreviewDrop(DragContext context) throws VetoDragException {
    super.onPreviewDrop(context);
    int newIndex = ???
  }
```

in onDrop() I can get the new position of a widget in the columnPanel with columnPanel.getWidgetIndex(widget) but in onPreviewDrop() I cannot do it because the widget is not inside the columnPanel at this time.

**How do I get the target index where a dropped Widget should be dropped into the columnPanel in onPreviewDrop()?** I want to know where the widget should be inserted before it is inserted. This way I can cancel the insertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following does only work if the positioner widget has the same structure as the placeholder when the row was dragged.

```
int newIndex = dropTarget.getWidgetIndex(newPositioner(context));
```

I use the following code to get the correct index:

```
   @Override
    public void onPreviewDrop(DragContext context)
        throws VetoDragException {
    super.onPreviewDrop(context);

    int newIndex = -1;
    String positionerClass = newPositioner(context).getElement()
        .getClassName();
    for (int i = 0; i < dropTarget.getWidgetCount(); i++) {
        String widgetClass = dropTarget.getWidget(i).getElement()
            .getClassName();
        if (widgetClass.equals(positionerClass)) {
        newIndex = i;
        }
    }
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```java
dropTarget.getWidgetIndex(newPositioner(context));
```

like this:

```java
@Override
public void onPreviewDrop(DragContext context) throws VetoDragException {
    super.onPreviewDrop(context);
    int newIndex = dropTarget.getWidgetIndex(newPositioner(context));
}
```

Comment: What is dropTarget? Is this my instance of the VerticalPanelDropController?

Comment: What is newPositioner()?

Comment: According to the sources `dropTarget` is a protected InsertPanel variable in AbstractInsertPanelDropController (ancestor class of VerticalPanelDropController). newPositioner is an abstract method from this class used by VerticalPanelDropController .

Comment: okay but it does not work because I always get the index -1. I think this is because that in onPreviewDrop the widget is not in the dropTarget. Do you see any other way to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any other idea?